# CreateObjectName static method not being autogenerated by EF tools

Tags: entity-framework

I'm creating an EF6 based application with Visual Studio 2013. I used the Model First approach, and after creating my data model in the editor, I can see and use the classes generated for my entities. But when following the documentation I tried to create a new instance of an entity with the static method CreateObjectName that is supposed to be autogenerated for each of the data model entities, I discovered that the autogenerated entities do not have such static methods, I can only create new instances with the new keyword. Here is the autogenerated code of one of my entities:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Movement
{
    public int IdMovement { get; set; }
    public MovementType Type { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> TargetAmount { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int IdTag { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdContainerSource { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdContainerTarget { get; set; }

    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public virtual Container ContainerSource { get; set; }
    public virtual Container ContainerTarget { get; set; }
}
```

I have T4 as the Code Generation Strategy, so according to the documentation I should have those methods. I have tried regenating the code, with no luck. I think that the CreateObject static method is cleaner that using new, so I would like to get EF to autogenerate them.

Any ideas?